# Batch execution - System cannot find the file specified

Tags: batch-file

My batch file is running the following code:

```
[...]
copy nul %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini

echo [OEMINFO]                               >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
echo OEMTextColor=                           >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
echo OEMBackGroundColor=                     >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
echo OEMNoStartupLogos=T                     >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
echo OEMInfoGreetings=                       >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
echo OEMIcon=<BD>\config\Default\cad.ico     >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
[...]
```

I always get the "system cannot find the file specified" error, but the ini file is correctly created with all the entries except for the last one (OEMIcon=\config\BormGroupERP\Default\cadt.ico).

At first i tried it with

```
echo "OEMIcon=<BD>\config\Default\cad.ico"    >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
```

which worked (no error message) but then I have the quotation marks in my ini file which is bad...

Also

```
echo [OEMIcon=<BD>\config\Default\cad.ico]    >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
```

does not work (same error again).

I also tried a little workaraound by storing the string in a variable (with quotationmarks) and then remove the quotation marks.

```
set OemIconData="OEMIcon=<BD>\config\Default\cad.ico" 
OemIconData=%OemIconData:~1,-1%
```

But the same error occured just when i try to remove the quotationmarks.

I'm out of ideas now. Why does that error occure? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<` and `>` are special characters that have their own reserved use.

`<` is an input re-directer, which sends everything **after** it into the command **before** itself.

`>` is an output re-directer, this sends everything **before** it to the location/ file/ command **after** itself.

Currently, `cmd.exe` executes as so:

- Gets the command result of `BD>\config\Default\cad.ico     >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini`
- Echo `echo OEMIcon=<BD` into `\config\Default\cad.ico     >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini`

---

We will need to escape the special character so `cmd` ignores it's usage, by adding a `^` in front of it. Your command should be:

```
echo OEMIcon=^<BD^>\config\Default\cad.ico     >> %BaseDir%\bin\MyIniFile.ini
```